# How to use two maps and make another map?

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, guava

I have two JSON and each JSON I am loading it in a Map. Just to make example simpler, I have shortened the JSON.

**First JSON**

```
{
    "abc": "2",
    "plmtq": "hello+world",
    "lndp": "def",
    "yyt": "opi"
}
```

I am loading this JSON in a map as `key:value` pair. Here `abc` is the key and `2` is the value. Let's call this `mapA`. This is a String to String map.

**Second JSON**

```
{
    "count": {
        "linkedTo": "abc"
    },
    "title": {
        "linkedTo": "plmtq",
        "decode": "true"
    },
    "cross": {
        "linkedTo": "lndp"
    },
    "browse": {
        "linkedTo": "lndp"
    }
}
```

I am also loading this JSON in a map. Let's call this `mapB`. And this is `Map<String, Map<Tag, String>>`. So in the `mapB`, key is `count` and value is another map in which key is `linkedTo` Tag enum and value is `abc` String. Similarly for others. I am also open in having a different format for this if it makes this problem simpler.

Here `Tag` is an enum class with these values. For now it only has two value but in general it has around 7-8 values.

```
  public enum Tag {
    linkedTo, decode;
  };
```

For example: Here `linkedTo` means value of `abc` will go into `count` variable. Similarly value of `plmtq` goes into `title` variable but with URL decoded as `decode` field is present and true.

**Problem Statement:**

Now I need to use these two maps and make a new map which will look like this and it will be String and String as well.

```
count=2
title=hello world // as you can see this got URL decoded with UTF-8 format.
cross=def
browse=def
yyt=opi
```

So each enum in the `Tag` class has special meanings and I need to perform certain operations accordingly. Right now it has two but in general it has 7-8. What is the best and efficient way to solve this  problem?

```
  private static Map<String, String> generateMap(final Map<String, String> mapA,
      final Map<String, Map<Tag, String>> mapB) {
    Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (Entry<String, Map<Tag, String>> entry : mapB.entrySet()) {
      String eventTag = entry.getKey();

      // I am confuse how to proceed further
    }
    return newMap;
  }
```

**Update:-**

After discussion with dimo, we came up this new JSON design for second map:

**SECOND JSON**

```
{
  "abc": {
      "renameTo": "count"
  },
  "plmtq": {
      "renameTo": "title",
      "decode": "true"
  },
  "lndp": {
      "renameTo": ["cross", "browse"],
     "decode": "true"
  }
}
```

It is just reverted format basically. So in the `newMap` key will be `count` and it's value will be value of `abc`. Similarly for `lndp` case, in the `newMap` key will be `cross` and `browse` and it's value will be `def` with URL decoded.

Comment: Why is `yyt=opi` in the output? It doesn't fit with the rest of the entries.

Comment: Whatever is remaining in `mapA`, I need to keep that as it is in the `newMap` as well.

Comment: Your `Tag`s need to be processed in a certain order (e.g. you can't decode if you don't know the value), so in the correct order check for existence of the tags in the secondary map and do whatever needs to be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I'm using Java 7 for most of this answer, but there's some Java 8 comments at the bottom.*

There's two key insights I think are important to start with:

- Use clear class, method, and variable names - names should convey meaning and purpose, whereas identifiers like `mapA` and `mapB` don't, making it difficult to reason about the problems you're trying to solve.
- Separate your problem into [smaller parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)); solve those parts in isolation, then put them together.

I'll try to apply both of these concepts here.

---

1. Convert the JSON into a meaningful and useful data structure (i.e. not just a bunch of `Map` objects). Your second JSON has some clear structure that isn't easy to work with as nested maps. Rather than trying to create complex algorithms to work with convoluted data, create objects that allow you to represent and interact with your data meaningfully.

   Consider representing your second JSON as a `Map<String, Transformation>`, where the `Transformation` class looks like so:

   ```
   public class Transformation {
     /** Applies one or more transformations to the provided entry. */
     public Entry<String, String> apply(Entry<String, String> e) {
       // ...
     }
   }
   ```

   What does `apply()` do? We'll get to that. For now it's good enough to have the class structure, because now we can write a simply function to do the processing you need.
2. With helpful data structures your task at hand becomes simple. Consider something like this (notice the clearer function and variable names):

   ```
   private static Map<String, String> decodeMap(
       Map<String, String> encodedData,
       Map<String, Transformation> transformations) {
     Map<String, String> decodedData = new HashMap<>();
     for (Entry<String, String> e : encodedData.entrySet()) {
       Transformation t = transformations.get(e.getKey());
       if (t == null) {
         t = Transformation.NO_OP; // just passes the entry through
       }
       Entry<String, String> decoded = t.apply(e);
       decodedData.put(decoded.getKey(), decoded.getValue());
     }
     return decodedData;
   }
   ```

   This is a pretty simple method; we iterate over every entry, apply a (possibly no-op) transformation, and construct a map of those transformed entries. Assuming our `Transformation` class does its job it should be fairly apparent that this method works.

   Notice that the keys of `transformations` are the *encoded* map's keys, not the decoded keys. This is a lot easier to work with, so ideally you'd invert your JSON to refect the same structure, but if you can't do that you just need to flip them in code before building the `Transformation` objects.
3. Now create the private business logic to encode your transformations inside the `Transformation` class. This might looks something like:

   ```
   public class Transformation {
     public static final Transformation NO_OP =
         new Transformation(ImmutableMap.of());

     private final Map<String, String> tasks;

     public Transformation(Map<String, String> tasks) {
       // could add some sanity checks here that tasks.keySet() doesn't
       // contain any unexpected values
       this.tasks = tasks;
     }

     public Entry<String, String> apply(Entry<String, String> e) {
       String key = e.getKey();
       String value = e.getValue();
       for (Entry<String, String> task : tasks.entrySet()) {
         switch (task.getKey()) {
           case "linkedTo":
             // this assumes we've inverted the old/new mapping. If not pass
             // the new key name into the constructor and use that here instead
             key = task.getValue();
             break;
           case "decode":
             if (Boolean.valueOf(task.getValue())) {
               // or whichever decoding function you prefer
               value = URLDecoder.decode(value);
             }
             break;
           // and so on
           default:
             throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                 "Unknown task " + task.getKey());
         }
       }
       return Maps.immutableEntry(key, value);
     }
   ```

   The `Transformation` class can handle as many tasks as you'd like, and no other code needs to be aware of the specifics.
4. The last step is to parse your JSON into this `Map<String, Transformation>` structure. I'll leave that up to you as it depends on your JSON parser of choice, however I suggest using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

---

Your requirement that the `lndp` entry be transformed into two separate entries with the same value is an odd one. It smells strongly to me like an [x-y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you're seeking help making this complex transformation logic work rather than exploring whether the underlying premise itself is flawed. Consider exploring that in a separate question where you spell out what you're starting with, where you're trying to go, and why your current solution seems best. Then people can offer suggestions on the strategy itself.

That said, we can still apply my second bullet point above to this problem. Rather than attempting to define transformation logic that supports multi-entry relationships, lets add a post-processing step to the transformation. Define a separate data structure that encodes which entries (in the new map) should be duplicated, e.g.

```
{
  "cross": ["browse"],
  ...
}
```

Then, `decodeMap()` would look something like this:

```
private static Map<String, String> decodeMap(
    Map<String, String> encodedData,
    Map<String, Transformation> transformations,
    Map<String, List<String>> duplications) {
  // ... existing method body
  for (Entry<String, List<String>> e : duplications) {
    String value = checkNotNull(decodedData.get(e.getKey()));
    for (String newKey : e.getValue()) {
      decodedData.put(newKey, value);
    }
  }
  return decodedData;
}
```

This is another example of separating the problem into smaller parts, rather than trying to solve everything in one fell swoop. You could even split these tasks into separate methods, so that `decodeMap()` doesn't itself become too complex.

---

You may notice that the `Transformation` class looks a lot like a [`Function`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Function.html) - that's because it essentially is one. You could add `implements Function<Entry<String, String>, Entry<String, String>>` (or in Java 8 `implements UnaryOperator<Entry<String, String>>`) and be able to use `Transformation` just like any other `Function`.

In particular this would allow you to make `Transformation` an interface and compose simple `Transformation` objects together, rather than define one massive type responsible for every task. You'd have a dedicated subclass of `Transformation` for each desired task, e.g.:

```
public RenameKeyTransformation implements Transformation {
  private final renameTo;
  public RenameKeyTransformation(String renameTo) {
    this.renameTo = checkNotNull(renameTo);
  }

  public Entry<String, String> apply(Entry<String, String> e) {
    return Maps.immutableEntry(renameTo, e.getValue());
  }
}
```

And so on. Then you can compose them with [`Functions.compose()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Functions.html#compose-com.google.common.base.Function-com.google.common.base.Function-) (or Java 8's [`Function.andThen()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#andThen-java.util.function.Function-)) to create a compound function that applies all the desired transformations. For example this:

```
Function<Entry<String, String>, Entry<String, String>> compound =
    Functions.compose(
        new RenameKeyTransformation("plmtq"),
        new UrlDecodeValue());
```

returns a new function that will apply both a rename-key operation and a url-decode-value operation to a given entry. You can repeatedly chain functions to apply as many transformations as you need.

The first `Transformation` object may be simpler to conceptualize (and it's a perfectly reasonable solution), but this second idea of composing small functions is taking the encapsulation idea mentioned above to another level, isolating each individual transformation task from one another and making it easy to add further transformations as you go. This is an example of the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), which is an elegant way to decouple the data you're processing from the exact processing steps to be carried out.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have few questions on this. I guess this is based on second JSON as you recommended for `mapB` right? I am trying to figure out how this will work for `lndp` case as I am confuse bcoz of array. I am in the same chat room, let me know once you are back. Btw, this is a great design, definitely understood how to add more fields as needed.

Comment: hey are you around? need some help with the array one in the second json you proposed.

Comment: @david yes, I'm around, but StackOverflow is something I do in my free time; there's no SLA :)

Comment: As far as handling the `lndp` case, I'd suggest spelling out (either in edits to this question, or in a new one) exactly what sort of transformations you expect to support. The problem with singular examples is it's hard for readers to intuit what your *intent* is, and therefore hard to propose a solution that addresses your intent. If I understand the underlying goal better, I may be able to offer an alternative.

Comment: sure yeah I understood. Sorry about that. I thought you were around may be that's why I pinged you. I am going to edit the question with the second json you proposed as we discussed. I had some code but it's very ugly I guess.

Comment: That said, you should also step back and ask yourself if you can solve your problem some other way. Needing to make complex, multi-key transformations of a map feels like a code-smell - can you accomplish what you need with a different, simpler design?

Comment: I edited the question with details. So for `lndp` case, `cross` will be the key and it's value will be `lndp` value in the `newMap`. Similarly `browse` will be key and it's value will be `lndp` value. And now let's say if there was a `decode` true present for `lndp`, then both `cross` and `browse` value will be url decoded.

Comment: I think you are right basically and that's why I am open for any design changes  for my second json which can help out to solve this problem in a more easier way.

Comment: @david like I said, it's hard to suggest helpful design changes without properly understanding the problem, and in particular which parts of your current solution can change. For example, perhaps you don't need the second JSON structure at all, and we could just define the necessary transformations in Java directly. That would work for some use cases but wouldn't work for others. I've add a suggestion for how to address the `lndp` case given what I know of your needs presently, if that isn't sufficient I'd suggest asking a new question.

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
private static Map<String, String> generateMap(final Map<String, String> mapA,
                                                  final Map<String, Map<Tag, String>> mapB) {
   Map<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<>();

   for (Map.Entry<String, Map<Tag, String>> entry : mapB.entrySet()) {
        String eventTag = entry.getKey();
        Map<Tag, String> values = entry.getValue();

        if (values.containsKey(Tag.linkedTo)) {
            String linkedValue = mapA.get(values.get(Tag.linkedTo));
            if (values.containsKey(Tag.decode)) {
                linkedValue = URLDecoder.decode(linkedValue);
            }

            newMap.put(eventTag, linkedValue);
        }
    }
    return newMap;
}
```

Or whatever you use for decoding...